# How to make opencart search bar as an autocomplete?

Tags: opencart2.3

I am working on OpenCart version 2.3. My need is to customize the opencart search bar as an autocomplete. How can it make possible. Hoping for some better guidance.
Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

many modules have for this, search with suggestion, search autocomplete.